# How to to try geocoding using Bing map rest APi . Post method

Tags: c#, rest, bing-maps

I referred this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/using-the-rest-services-with-net and wrote the below code.

```
             public void Geocode(string BingMapKey,string addressToBeGeocoded)
             {
                  Uri geocodeRequest = new Uri(string.Format("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?key={0}", BingMapKey));
                            GetPOSTResponse(geocodeRequest,addressToBeGeocoded, (x) =>
                            {
                                if (!(x.ResourceSets[0].Resources.Length > 0))// atleast one matching result has come.0 is the best matching result
                                {
                                    geocodeNotFound=true;
                                }
                            else
                                {

                                    BingMapsRESTService.Common.JSON.Location val = x.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0] as BingMapsRESTService.Common.JSON.Location;
                                    var latitude = val.GeocodePoints[0].Coordinates[0];
                                    var longitude = val.GeocodePoints[0].Coordinates[1];
                                }
                            }
                }

            private void GetPOSTResponse(Uri uri, string data, Action<BingMapsRESTService.Common.JSON.Response> callback)
            {
                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

                        request.Method = "POST";
                        request.ContentType = "text/plain;charset=utf-8";

                        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
                        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);

                        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

                        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                        {
                            // Send the data.  
                            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        }

                        request.BeginGetResponse((x) =>
                        {
                            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(x))
                            {
                                if (callback != null)
                                {
                                    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BingMapsRESTService.Common.JSON.Response));
                                    try
                                    {
                                        callback(ser.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream()) as BingMapsRESTService.Common.JSON.Response);
                                    }

                                    catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        errorCount++;
                                    }
                            }
                            }
                        }, null);
            }
```

But it gives me error:
            `{"The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."}`

instead if i use the GET call as mentioned in the link's example by bing, it works. I want to use post call.

i do not know how exactly `Uri geocodeRequest = new Uri(string.Format("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/key={0}", bingMapKey));` should look like. I am thinking that the address will be in the body. Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you perhaps tidy your code, and format your error using block quotes. It makes it easier for everyone to read

Comment: May I ask why you want to use a post call?

Answer (score 0):

The Location API in Bing Maps only supports GET, not POST. This used to be documented at the top of each service documentation page, but I'm not seeing it anymore. It looks like the Bing Maps team just migrated their documentation from MSDN to learn.microsoft.com in the past few weeks.

You might also want to consider using Microsoft's newer enterprise mapping platform; Azure Maps. It has more features, has higher free usage limits, is generally cheaper beyond the free limits, receives data updates much more regularly than Bing Maps, and is an Azure cloud service. For simple individual geocode requests, it only supports GET requests as well (most mapping platforms are like this), but for more advanced search queries there is support for POST requests. You can find a like of the search services in Azure Maps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search

Here are some additional resources on Azure Maps:

- Main site: https://azure.com/maps
- Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/
- Code Sample gallery: https://aka.ms/AzureMapsSamples